# Restful service with .net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

Microsoft is encouraging developers to use asp.net web api for creating Restful services. I have done some [googling](https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?rlz=1C1_____enPK456PK456&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=h9&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=.net%20web%20api%20tutorial&cp=8&gs_id=5m&xhr=t&q=.net%204.0%20web%20api%20with&pf=p&rlz=1C1_____enPK456PK456&sclient=psy-ab&oq=.net%204.0%20web%20api%20with%20&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=beafa4bc4f8a5807&ix=h9&biw=1366&bih=624)
http://www.matlus.com/asp-net-web-api-with-webforms/

it seems to me that i can use it with .net 4.5 but not with 4.0. In .net 4.0 what are my options for creating Restful service. is it only wcf web api or something else that should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create asp.net web api service without installing .net 4.5, you only need to [install](http://www.asp.net/web-api) asp.net mvc 4 for VS2010 and normally use for .net 4.0. Alternative, you can use WCF service or asp.net mvc controllers for REST architecture, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx) example with asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1):

A small mistake of yours, there is no WCF Web Api anymore. That was the original name, then it was renamed ASP.NET Web Api.

You can use it with .NET 4.0. Just install ASP.NET MVC 4 and you get Web Api. But it's still in Beta...

Comment: Thanks Dante for your response